# How do I adjust parameters of a RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URL:

```
http://example.org/wiki/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin
&returnto=Special%3AWatchlist&returntoquery=&warning=watchlistanontext
```

and I want the request to be redirected to:

```
https://example.org/login/wiki/?returnTo=Special%3AWatchlist
```

The part `title=Special:UserLogin` is the one, which should trigger the `RewriteRule`. The other parameters can change (especially the value of `returnto=xxx`); it should be preserved for the target URL. The parameter `returnto=xxx` should be mapped to `returnTo=xxx` (with uppercase "T") in the target URL.

After reading [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) I have tried with this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} title=Special:UserLogin&?(.*)
RewriteRule index.php https://example.org/login/wiki/?%1 [R=301,L]
```

As far as I can tell this is also basically working, except one thing: The returnto parameter is still written `returnto` and not `returnTo`. How can I change the casing of the parameter name to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your regex to capture correct query parameter. You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)title=Special:UserLogin(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)returnto=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://example.org/login/wiki/?returnTo=%1 [R=301,L]
```